# java: NoSuchElementException: Reading to arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

sorry if my formatting is garbage. 
I'm trying to add 2 strings and a boolean to an arrayList doing the following.

```
while((in.hasNextLine())){
    list.add(new Task(in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()));
    }
```

I keep getting a no such element exception. If I take the while loop away like so

```
list.add(new Task(in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()));
```

It functions fine but I can only add the first line of the text file. 
Is there something wrong in the loop or with the Scanner?

```
try {
        in = new Scanner(f1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while((in.hasNextLine())){
    list.add(new Task(in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()));
    }
```

f1 is declared as File f1 = new File ("src/mylist.txt");

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: `in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()` What do you think with this?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: `hasNextBoolean()` does not consume the boolean value. --- Also, after the last `next()` (or `nextBoolean()`) call, the "cursor" is still at the end of the line, so if your last line ends with a newline, `hasNextLine()` will return true, even though there are no more elements. --- Using `Scanner` to read lines of 3 values like that is *very* error-prone. Suggest using `BufferedReader`, `readLine()` and `split()`, for more controlled parsing.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try a few of those methods and see if I can get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` exception is throwed by `in.next()`, in `list.add(new Task(in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()))`,.

and for `in.next()`, if you don't use any `Pattern` in `Scanner` to match the next token. it will use default `Pattern` `private static Pattern FIND_ANY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?s).*")` to match whole line. it will cause `in.next()` will read whole line.

so `list.add(new Task(in.next(),in.next(), in.hasNextBoolean()))` will throw `NoSuchElementException`, you have read twice but you only check once.